# Order Numerically and then Alphabetically in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, sorting

I need to sort a table by ascending order of a project number. My table has several rows of data containing a column called project number. The text below shows what a part of the rows in my table.

```
-- project number --
       1199.7
       1053.2
       1020
       1023-D
       1023-C
       1023-B
       50
       34.3T
       870-W
```

Here is my query in codeigniter:

```
$this->db->select('Project');
$this->db->from('`active_projects`');
$this->db->order_by('Project');
```

`Project` is the column in question. Can anybody help me modify my query so it sorts on the basis of numerics and alphabetically in ascending order?

In other words, the correct sorting should look like:

```
-- project number --
       50
       34.3T
       870-W
       1020
       1023-B
       1023-C
       1023-D
       1053.2
       1199.7
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does silent conversion from strings to numbers, when a string is used in an arithmetic context.

This is highly convenient for what you want to do.  You can just do:

```
order by project + 0, project
```